# Select box won't populate with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to populate a select box in my page but its not working, the select box displays but its completely empty.

I also get no error in my console.

My script is this:

```
        var select = document.createElement("select");
            for(var i in resource){
                if(i !== id && select.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    select.setAttribute(i, resource[i].name);
                }
            }
            d.appendChild(select);
```

Example data for `resource`:

```
{
 "1":{"name":"Test"},
 "2":{"name":"Test2"},
 "3":{"name":"Test3"}
}
```

Any ideas on why it won't populate?

Comment: What are you expecting that to do? If you want those to be options in your drop-down you have to create [option elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option)? What do 'name' and 'type' correspond to?

Comment: Those are just object properties I'm using to populate the select box. Well not type - ignore that property of the object.

Comment: OK, but what do they correspond to in terms of your drop-down. Is 'name' the text which is displayed for each option in the list?

Comment: Yes and the the `i` will be the object such as resource[1] etc

Comment: Thats what i thought setAttribute was meant to do any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite few mistakes in your script, many are mentioned in the comments as you can see.

What you are looking for might be something like this

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
for(var i in resource){
    if(resource.hasOwnProperty(i)){ //removed the i !== id condition, you may put it back
        var opt = new Option(resource[i].name, i);
        select.options[select.options.length] = opt;
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjzF6/)

Comment: this must be a typo i guess.. opt should be `Option(resource[i].name, i)` first parameter is for text and second for value!

Comment: @razzak yes, in the fiddle it was corrected forgot to copy here

Comment: Ah i see so when does setAttribute get used for anything ?

Comment: Should also mention shouldn't `resource.hasOwnProperty(i)` be `!resource.hasOwnProperty(i)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny if it has its own property then it should skip rather than make it again surely?

Comment: @Dave no the purpose of [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is different, in javascript an object can inherit properties from other object like `toString`, when we iterate through an object's properties we want to be sure that the property belongs to the object itself and not an inherited one. It is not used to check whether the given option is already present in the select box

Comment: Hmm when i have it - the select doesn't populate but if i'm checking for it to be false then it works ??

Comment: @Dave then there is something wrong with the `resource` object. can you share the `resource` object, because whatever sample you have given it is working fine

Comment: There is example data in the question for `resource`

Comment: @Dave if you see the attached demo in my answer it used the resource and seems to be fine

Comment: @Dave Can you help to reproduce the case in the demo

Comment: @ArunPJohny sure please hold :)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I can't seem to reproduce the results on fiddle.

Comment: @Dave which is the browser used? are you familiar with debugging using browser developer tools

Comment: Chrome latest version ! Console has no errors. HTML shows no info in the select box.

`<select style="margin: 0px auto; width: 250px;" name="link"></select>`

Comment: Can you add `console.log('resource', resource, i, resource.hasOwnProperty(i))` before the `if` condition and see the console

Comment: I've solved it - stupid browser cache even though i disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create child elements of the `select`, that are `option` tags.

Here's a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2tcj/).